# Why is my listview header invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My list view header is invisible.

My code:

```
ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
header.Text = "Manufacture Name";
header.Width = 150;
listView_manufacture.Columns.Add(header);
listView_manufacture.View = View.Details;
listView_manufacture.CheckBoxes = true;
```

Where is my error?

Comment: The code you've posted works as-is on my machine.  Your problem might be related to something else that was not included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> > use bellow  code or follow this link:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET

code:

```
    GridView myGridView = new GridView();
    myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = true; 
    myGridView.ColumnHeaderToolTip = "Employee Information";

    GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
    gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("FirstName");
    gvc1.Header = "FirstName";
    gvc1.Width = 100;
    myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc1);
    GridViewColumn gvc2 = new GridViewColumn();
    gvc2.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("LastName");
    gvc2.Header = "Last Name";
    gvc2.Width = 100;
    myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc2);
    GridViewColumn gvc3 = new GridViewColumn();
    gvc3.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("EmployeeNumber");
    gvc3.Header = "Employee No.";
    gvc3.Width = 100;
    myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc3);

   listView.View = myGridView;
```

Comment: The question is about WinForms.